# Upload files from a single HTML form to PHP for 'multiple' different file inputs?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a simple page that has 9 block regions, for each region - the user can select an image for the "menu" and another image for the "content" of that region.

They can then upload those images with a submit button "Upload files for this region".

There is also a 'save' / submit at the top of the page.

The page uses one big form (it was lots of multiple smaller forms for each region, which worked but I wanted to set it as 1 form since I needed to submit everything at once).

My HTML page is basically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/zoombox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="well well-large">
      <h1>Configuration page</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rowspace row">
        <div class="column span3">
          <h4>Content: 1</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[1][home]" id="fileData[1][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[1][content]" id="fileData[1][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>

        <div class="column offset1 span3">
          <h4>Content: 2</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[2][home]" id="fileData[2][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[2][content]" id="fileData[2][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>

        <div class="column offset1 span3">
          <h4>Content: 3</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[3][home]" id="fileData[3][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[3][content]" id="fileData[3][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rowspace row">
        <div class="column span3">
          <h4>Content: 4</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[4][home]" id="fileData[4][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[4][content]" id="fileData[4][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>

        <div class="column offset1 span3">
          <h4>Content: 5</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[5][home]" id="fileData[5][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[5][content]" id="fileData[5][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>

        <div class="column offset1 span3">
          <h4>Content: 6</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[6][home]" id="fileData[6][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[6][content]" id="fileData[6][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rowspace row">
        <div class="column span3">
          <h4>Content: 7</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[7][home]" id="fileData[7][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[7][content]" id="fileData[7][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>

        <div class="column offset1 span3">
          <h4>Content: 8</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[8][home]" id="fileData[8][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[8][content]" id="fileData[8][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>

        <div class="column offset1 span3">
          <h4>Content: 9</h4>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[9][home]" id="fileData[9][home]" title="Select MENU image"><br>

            <input type="file" name="fileData[9][content]" id="fileData[9][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rowspace row">
        <div class="column span3">
          <h4>Map Content</h4>
            <input type="file" name="fileData[10][content]" id="fileData[10][content]" title="Select CONTENT image"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zoombox.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
    $('.zoombox').zoombox();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My **var_dump($_FILES)** output is:

```
<?php

array(1) {
  ["fileData"]=> array(5) {
    ["name"]=> array(10) {
      [1]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [2]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [3]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [4]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [5]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [6]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [7]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [8]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(5) "8.png" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [9]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [10]=> array(1) {
        ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }

    }
    ["type"]=> array(10) {
      [1]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [2]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [3]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [4]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [5]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [6]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [7]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [8]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [9]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [10]=> array(1) {
        ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }

    }
    ["tmp_name"]=> array(10) {
      [1]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [2]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [3]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [4]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [5]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [6]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [7]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [8]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php2DdwXG" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [9]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }
      [10]=> array(1) {
        ["content"]=> string(0) ""
      }

    }
    ["error"]=> array(10) {
      [1]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [2]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [3]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [4]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [5]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [6]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [7]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [8]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [9]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(4) ["content"]=> int(4)
      }
      [10]=> array(1) {
        ["content"]=> int(4)
      }

    }
    ["size"]=> array(10) {
      [1]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [2]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [3]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [4]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [5]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [6]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [7]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [8]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(210379) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [9]=> array(2) {
        ["home"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> int(0)
      }
      [10]=> array(1) {
        ["content"]=> int(0)
      }

    }

  }

}
```

I'm guessing it's something from with my HTML page? It was working fine before I tried to 'refactor' it into one form instead of ~20 forms...

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was because I had the same name value for all the submit buttons... changed each submit button to be a different name and it's working fine now.